# Exec format error while python installation in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, cython, arm64

I'm trying to install `cython:arm64`, this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get -y upgrade && \
echo deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic main >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic universe >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates main >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
echo deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security main >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -f \
    cython:arm64
```

`cython:arm64` has a dependency on `python2.7-minimal:arm64`, so this packet is being installed as well and there is exec format error while python installation:

```
Setting up python2.7-minimal:arm64 (2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.6) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-minimal.postinst: 42: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-minimal.postinst: /usr/bin/python2.7: Exec format error
dpkg: error processing package python2.7-minimal:arm64 (--configure):
 installed python2.7-minimal:arm64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
```

How to avoid this issue and install `cython:arm64`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support this, you need to install qemu packages on **host machine** before build your docker image:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static
```

Then, use next to register the binfmt:

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:2 .
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
......
Step 2/3 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && echo deb [arch=amd64] 
......
Step 3/3 : RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64 &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y -f     cython:arm64
...
Setting up libsqlite3-0:arm64 (3.22.0-1ubuntu0.4) ...
Setting up libstdc++6:arm64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libffi6:arm64 (3.2.1-8) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up manpages-dev (4.15-1) ...
Setting up libc6-dev:arm64 (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up libitm1:arm64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-stdlib:arm64 (2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up libisl19:arm64 (0.19-1) ...
Setting up libcc1-0:arm64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libasan4:arm64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libbinutils:arm64 (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.5) ...
Setting up libubsan0:arm64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libmpfr6:arm64 (4.0.1-1) ...
Setting up python2.7:arm64 (2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up file (1:5.32-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Setting up libgcc-7-dev:arm64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libpython-stdlib:arm64 (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Setting up libpython2.7:arm64 (2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up libexpat1-dev:arm64 (2.2.5-3ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libmpc3:arm64 (1.1.0-1) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-dev:arm64 (2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up binutils:arm64 (2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.5) ...
Setting up python2.7-dev:arm64 (2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up python:arm64 (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Setting up libpython-dev:arm64 (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Setting up python-dev:arm64 (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Setting up cython:arm64 (0.26.1-0.4) ...
Setting up cpp-7:arm64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up cpp:arm64 (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up gcc-7:arm64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up gcc:arm64 (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
Removing intermediate container 995d04075a29
 ---> 555cac76aa77
Successfully built 555cac76aa77
Successfully tagged abc:2
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've got another error after these packets installation: 
`Setting up python2.7-minimal:arm64 (2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.6) ... 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-minimal.postinst: 42: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-minimal.postinst: /usr/bin/python2.7: not found`
I tried to install python via apt-get explicitly but got the same error.

Comment: This is strange as it works on my side, have you installed `sudo apt-get install qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static` on docker host? Or just write it in dockerfile? What's your host os?

Comment: Yes, I installed these packages on docker host, dokerfile remains the same. 
I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Do I need to reboot PC after installation?

Comment: @Alex I guess I missed qemu bin format register, update the answer. You need to use `docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes` before build your own dockerfile.

Comment: you are right, your docker run command helps. `cpython` has been installed. Thank you!